# How to embed images from Flickr so image appears on website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, flickr

I was wondering how I could embed pictures from FLICKR onto the website, right now, I can only get the URL's of the image, but I wanted to get the whole image with it. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    API_KEY = 'YOURAPIKEY'; //INSERT API KEY
    USER_ID = '28858578@N06'; //ENTER USER ID

    var photolist = [];

    $.getJSON('https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=' + API_KEY + '&user_id=' + USER_ID + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(rest) {

        var numPhotos = rest.photos.pages;

        for (var u =1; u < numPhotos + 1; u++) {    
            $.getJSON('https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=' + API_KEY + '&user_id=' + USER_ID + '&format=json&page=' + u + '&jsoncallback=?', function(results) { var targetDiv = $('#fotolist')
                for (var m =0; m < results.photos.total; m++) {
                  targetDiv.append("https://www.flickr.com/" + 
results.photos.photo[m].owner + "/" + results.photos.photo[m].id + "<br />");
                    photolist.push("https://www.flickr.com/" + results.photos.photo[m].owner + "/" + results.photos.photo[m].id);


                }      
            });
        }    
    }); 
});
  </script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="fotolist">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can put that link withing img attributes in DOM(html) via jQuery.

Comment: For each link create an image tag with src attribute to that link and then add that tag to DOM via jQuery

Comment: @user2686338 How do I take each of those links and make them the source of a new image?

Comment: There is a WordPress plugin called Awesome Flickr Gallery that does just that, here http://www.ronakg.com/projects/awesome-flickr-gallery-wordpress-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

if photolist contains array of links of images

```
var fotolist = $('#fotolist');
jQuery.each(photolist , function(index, value){
 fotolist.append('<img src="'+value+'">');
 });
```